# How to set relatively address to write a file in JAVA?

Tags: java, file, path, relative-path, absolute-path

When I write a string to a file, Java writes the file in project's root directory.

I want to write in a subdirectory. For example : `project_root/my_subdir`.

It is possible to write a file to an absolute path? It would be much better if my program was able to work on another system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the file as

```
new File("project_root/my_subdir", newFileToCreate);
```

or perhaps

```
new File("project_root" + File.separator + "my_subdir", newFileToCreate);
```

to keep this OS independent

or you can use file to as the first parameter

```
new File(new File("project_root" + File.separator + "my_subdir"), newFileToCreate);
```

Comment: I believe `/` is OS-independent in Java!

Comment: I think you can use `File.seperator` to get the system implementation

Comment: Thank you! 
File.separator is very useful! It was my second question ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well, you are looking for:

```
File file = new File("./my_subdir/file.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you!
And another question : will work right slashes in windows, or I'm forced to write ".\\my_subdir\\file.txt" ?

Comment: @Danila `/` would work across all platforms, including Windows :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are asking how to create a File with a relative path so that it will work when you deploy it to another computer.  You can get the user's home directory `System.getProperty("user.home")` or the current working directory `System.getProperty("user.dir")`.

For example, to create a file in a user's home directory, you might do: 
`new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "myFile.txt")`.